# Installation Maven Eclipse 3.8 time out connection repository errors

Tags: eclipse, maven, time, installation, out

I installed

```
Eclipse Platform

Version: 3.8.1
Build id: M20120914-1540
```

And I want to install Maven.

I followed the steps:

```
Help->Install New Software
M2Eclipse" and Location as http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3
```

I get the following error in the installation software

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=PlatformProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to connect to repository http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3/1.3.1.20130219-1424/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.archetype.common_1.3.1.20130219-0923.jar
Connection timed out: connect
Unable to connect to repository http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3/1.3.1.20130219-1424/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.indexer_1.3.1.20130219-0923.jar
Connection timed out: connect
Unable to connect to repository http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3/1.3.1.20130219-1424/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.3.1.20130219-0923.jar
Connection timed out: connect
Unable to connect to repository http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3/1.3.1.20130219-1424/plugins/org.jboss.netty_3.2.5.Final-20130219-0923.jar
Connection timed out: connect
```

Configuration proxy is

[image]

EDITED

I see in the log

```
 http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.4/1.4.1.20140328-1905/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.4.1.20140328-1501.jar failed on Connection timed out: connect. Retry attempt 0 started
!STACK 0
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

Do I have to change the eclipse proxy configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Try to access the plugin website through browser. If you are able to see the page, change yhe proxy settings in eclipse to use Dynamic proxy.

P.S. : Restart is needed if you change the settings.